# WebClient should ignore unsucessful requests

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

The following code causes an empty list if url1 returns many results but url2 returns a 404. How to ignore error properly and just continue with the succesful responses of url1?

```
        Set<String> list = new HashSet<>();

    Mono<String> first = WebClient.create(url1)
            .get()
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String.class)
            .onErrorResume(e -> {
                return Mono.empty();
            });

    Mono<String> two = WebClient.create()
            .get()
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String.class)
            .onErrorResume(e -> {
                return Mono.empty();
            });

    Flux.zip(first, two)
            .doOnComplete(() -> System.out.printf("done: %d\n", list.size()))
            .subscribe(
                    responses -> {
                        for (Object response : responses) {
                            String[] lines = ((String)response).split("\n");
                            for(String line : lines) {
                                list.add(line);
                            }
                        }
                    }
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

I've simplified your example, replacing the two webclient calls with their expected output, mainly for demonstration purposes.

You can use `merge` instead `zip`, to avoid the entire `Flux` returning empty if one single source is empty.

```java
Flux.merge(Mono.just("1\n2\n3"), Mono.empty())
                .doOnComplete(() -> System.out.printf("done: %d\n", list.size()))
                .subscribe(
                        responses -> {
                            List<String> stringList = Arrays.stream(responses.split("\n")).collect(Collectors.toList());
                            stringList.forEach(System.out::println);
                        });
```

[JavaDoc](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#merge-org.reactivestreams.Publisher...-)

*NOTE*

It's worth mentioning that processing the result in the `subscribe` method and adding it to a variable defined outside of the reactive stream is a little unusual. The more expected use case would be to process the data in a `flatMap`/`map` and return either a `Mono<List<String>>` or `Flux<String>` out of your method ie.

*Example returning a `Mono<List<String>>`*

```java
Flux.merge(Mono.just("1\n2\n3"), Mono.empty())
                .doOnComplete(() -> System.out.printf("done: %d\n", list.size()))
                .flatMap(strings -> Flux.fromArray(strings.split("\n")))
                .collectList()
```